# Jquery plugin not working with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-tags-input

I'm new to RoR and JS and could use some help understanding how some of these pieces fit together.  I've read a number of resources and I thought I understood what to do, but something is still escaping me.

I want to create an interface for entering tags, much like the one here on Stack Overflow.  I found the following plugin that has all the features I would eventually like to fiddle with: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

So here is what I did:

1) I downloaded the zip.
2) I placed *jquery.tagsinput.js* and *jquery.tagsinput.min.js* into *vendor/assets/javascripts*.
3) I placed *jquery.tagsinput.css* into *vendor/assets/stylesheets*.
4) In my *views/nuggets/index.html.erb*, I added `<input name="tags" id="tags" value="foo,bar,baz" />`
5) In my *app/assets/javascripts/nuggets.js.coffee*, I added `$('#tags').tagsInput();`

When I noticed that the input was not working as expected, I checked the page's source and noticed that the following lines were not there:
`<script src="jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tagsinput.css" />`

As a result, I thought I should add `//= require jquery.tagsinput` to *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* and `*= require jquery.tagsinput` to  *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*.

I'm sure this will all seem very trivial in retrospect, but I'm quite lost at this point.

Thanks for your help,

Grasswistle

**Edit, adding info for @user1965817:**
Contents of *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.tagsinput
```

Contents of *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

*= require jquery.tagsinput

body 
{
    background-color:#C5C5F0;
    font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.header 
{
    font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;

    top: 0px;
    margin:0px;  
    padding: 0px 2px 2px 3px;   
    margin-bottom: 70px; 
    border-width: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your CSS Is Incorrect**

You need to keep the require statements at the top of your file (not seperated):

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.tagsinput
 */
```

**Have You Initialized The Tags JS?**

In order to initialize the script, you have to be able to "call" the plugin, like this:

```
$('#tags').tagsInput({
    //parameters here
});
```